# Build web graph with wget

Tags: graph, web-crawler, wget

I'm using wget with -r (recursive) option, to crawl and download all the pages starting from a root.

For debugging purpose I'd like to output which page routed me to another one, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/ -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions

Is there such a way to do that?

Please note that I need explicitly use wget.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found untill now is to use the `--warc-file` option, to export a [warc archive](http://bibnum.bnf.fr/WARC/) of my crawl. This format also store the Referer.

Using a [python library](https://github.com/internetarchive/warc) to read the output I wrote the following simple script, to export a csv with source/target columns:

```
import warc
f = warc.open("crawler.warc")
for record in f:
    if record['WARC-Type'] != 'request':
        continue
    for line in record.payload:
        if line.startswith("Referer:"):
            print line.replace("Referer: ", "").strip('\n\r'), ",", record['WARC-Target-URI']
```